# Synchronizing billing fields with the corresponding shipping fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

How can I refactor this redundant code?

```
$("#txtShippingAddressFullName").change(function () {
    $("#txtBillingAddressFullName").val($(this).val());
})

$("#txtShippingAddress").change(function () {
    $("#txtBillingAddress").val($(this).val());
})

$("#txtShippingPostalCode").change(function () {
    $("#txtBillingPostalCode").val($(this).val());
})

$("#txtShippingPhoneNumber").change(function () {
    $("#txtBillingPhoneNumber").val($(this).val());
})

$("#ddlShippingCity").change(function () {
    $("#ddlBillingCity").val($(this).val());
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Since I don't know your markup, I don't know for sure if this will work, but it might

```
$("input[id*=Shipping]").change(function (event) {
  var billingId = this.id.replace('Shipping', 'Billing');
  $("#" + billingId).val($(this).val());
});
```

Basically, get every input with "Shipping" in its id, and when such an input changes, use its id to determine the corresponding billing-input.

*Edit: While this solution is a neat little demonstration of the attribute-value-contains selector, it is - as the other answers have pointed out - better to use a class or data-attribute*

Answer (score 5):

The prettiest way to do it, would be with HTML 5 data attribute:

```
<input id="txtShippingAddress" data-syncwith-id="txtBillinAddress">
<input id="txtShippingPostalCode" data-syncwith-id="txtBillingPostalCode">
<input id="txtShippingAddressFullName" data-syncwith-id="txtBillinAddressFullName">
```

Then in your javscript:

```
$("input[data-syncwith-id]").change(function (event) {
  $("#" + $(this).data("syncwith-id")).val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: This solution is more flexible since it doesn't restrict a rule for the new name.

Answer (score 4):

Improving Flambino's answer, I think you should create a class for these elements and select them by the class.

```
$(".elements-to-replace").change(function (event) {
  var billingId = this.id.replace('Shipping', 'Billing');
  $("#" + billingId).val($(this).val());
});
```